# Java alignment swing components

Tags: java, swing, alignment, jbutton, layout-manager

I can't to fix some problem:

I have a program with `JPanel` that uses `BoxLayout` with alignment by `X_AXIS` and inside 2 `JLabel (setAignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT))`, 2 `JTextArea` and 1 `JButton(setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT))`.

when I press button and button changes text's button changes alignment labels and button too(not size only). If it making often it's very nervous for eyes. `setHorizontalAlignment` and `SwingConstants` does not work.

bit GUI design:

```
frame = new JFrame("TestIOapp");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
panel.setBackground(Color.decode("#e2dad4"));

JLabel qLabel = new JLabel("Question");
JLabel aLabel = new JLabel("Answer");
qLabel.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
aLabel.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

button = new JButton("Next");
button.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,40));
button.addActionListener(new NextButtonListener());        

question = new JTextArea(10,20);
question.setWrapStyleWord(true);
question.setLineWrap(true);
answer = new JTextArea(10,20);
answer.setWrapStyleWord(true);
answer.setLineWrap(true);

JScrollPane qScroll = new JScrollPane(question);
qScroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
qScroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
JScrollPane aScroll = new JScrollPane(answer);
aScroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
aScroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

panel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,10)));
panel.add(qLabel);
panel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,10)));
panel.add(qScroll);
panel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,10)));
panel.add(aLabel);
panel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,10)));
panel.add(aScroll);
panel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,10)));
panel.add(button);
panel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,30)));

frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, panel);
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.setSize(500,500);
```

[image]

Comment: Box layout is really difficult to use for anything but the simplest layouts.  I'd recommend you skip any further attempt to get it working and just go straight for a gui layout tool such as Matisse for NetBeans.  It is far easier to use than trying to mess with low-level constraints in a layout manager.

Comment: Box layout tutorial is here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html  I'd recommend that you set up your code like the demo halfway down the page, and then post it here.  Someone might be able to work through it and figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Provide a more complete snippet of your code

Comment: It is usually bad UI experience to have button change its text. Try to set button size big enough so that it will accommodate both texts without resizing.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used.

Comment: @markspace I understand it but I just began to study programming and thought that it will be better try to digging by manual in a code

Comment: All components should use a center alignment, including the scroll panes.